# Multiple update statements using values prior to transaction start MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions

I'm trying to run multiple update statements within a MySQL transaction, but I need the WHERE clauses in each to reference the values existing before the start of the transaction.  (Using innoDB table.)

For example, I have the following table of flights (simplified, obviously):

```
flight  aircraft     dep_time
1       1            05:00
2       1            06:00
3       1            07:00

4       2            05:00
5       2            06:00
6       2            07:00
```

What I need to be able to do is swap flights on aircraft 1 departing 06:00 or later with flights on aircraft 2 departing at 06:00 or later.  I currently do this by assigning an intermediate aircraft to each flight, then updating the flights with this intermediate aircraft to the desired aircraft.  For example:

```
UPDATE flights SET aircraft = 1001 WHERE aircraft = 1 AND dep_time >= 06:00
UPDATE flights SET aircraft = 1002 WHERE aircraft = 2 AND dep_time >= 06:00
UPDATE flights SET aircraft = 2 WHERE aircraft = 1001
UPDATE flights SET aircraft = 1 WHERE aircraft = 1002
```

It seems like I could avoid the two additional update statements by using a transaction.  Additionally, the method I'm using now would cause a major problem if there was actually an aircraft 1001 in the database (I'm just using a very large number at this point to make sure this doesn't occur) ... something I'd like to avoid.  My intent is to do something like this:

```
START TRANSACTION();
UPDATE flights SET aircraft = 2 WHERE aircraft = 1 AND dep_time >= 06:00
UPDATE flights SET aircraft = 1 WHERE aircraft = 2 AND dep_time >= 06:00
COMMIT();
```

As I understand it, the second update statement will see the values that were updated in the first statement, which will mess everything up.  Is there a way I can make both UPDATE statements use the values that existed when the transaction was started?  If not, does anyone have a better suggestion on how to handle this?

My desired outcome is this:

```
flight  aircraft     dep_time
1       1            05:00
2       2            06:00
3       2            07:00

4       2            05:00
5       1            06:00
6       1            07:00
```

Thank you!  I apologize if this isn't clear...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add unique column to your table (usually it will have name `id` and to be unsigned big int auto_increment type)

Then you will be able to swap rows as you wish, as soon as each row will have unique id.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really about transactions at all, it's about using UPDATE to swap values (whether inside a single transaction or not).  Transactions don't "save the data that exists at the start of the transaction" the way your question implies:  You seem to be misunderstanding what they're for.  You can `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` an in-progress transaction, but you can't write queries that refer explicitly to current vs. pre-transaction DB data.

If you need to "save" the data at a given point in time, you could copy it to a temporary table, or to another column that you creat in your current table just for this (temporary storage) purpose.

However, a simpler solution is this:  If you can write the entire thing as a *single* update statement, then you won't have a problem, since each row will only be processed once by a single `UPDATE`, e.g.:

```
UPDATE flights SET aircraft = IF(aircraft=1,2,1) WHERE (aircraft = 1 OR aircraft = 2) AND dep_time >= 06:00
```

should solve your problem in this particular case.

(That said, bear in mind that if you are updating a primary or unique key, the rows are still updated one-by-one and this can cause duplicate key errors, even if the *final* result of the update wouldn't have any.  So in such cases you may have to either order the update carefully using `ORDER BY`, or else you might have to temporarily insert dummy values and use multiple `UPDATE` statements, the way you're currently doing it.)